# Android code For Following JSON Pattern

Tags: android, json

Want Android Code For Following JSON Format...Bit Confused How to fetch value of array For Following Pattern..

```
{
    "params": [
        {
            "answer_data_all": [
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "question_id": "14"
                }
            ],
            "form_data_all": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "form 1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you want to parse a JSON, the Gson library is the way to go

Comment: from where are you getting this JSON, i think this is not json , somebody pointed out that "{" is called as objects and "[" is called as array in json.

Comment: I don't think it is valid json format. I have never seen `Object -{ in json

Comment: I have Updated the JSOn Format

Answer (score 0):

Parsing a JSON is fairly simple. You could use [GSON library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson) by Google for example. Below is an example I wrote for your object/model:

```
class MyObject{
    ArrayList<Params> params;

    class Params {
        ArrayList<AnswerData> answer_data_all;
        ArrayList<FormData> form_data_all;

        class AnswerData {
            String id;
            String question_id;
        }

        class FormData {
            String id;
            String name;
        }
    }
}
```

And then get an instance of your object with:

`MyObject myObject =  (MyObject) (new Gson()).toJson("..json..", MyObject.class);`

Answer (score 0):

You just have some nested `JSONArray` and `JSONObject`. Assuming you have this response in string format all you have to do is create  `JSONObject` from that string and then extract what you need. As someone mentioned [ ] encloses `JSONArray` while { } encloses `JSONObject`

```
JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(stringResponse);
JSONArray params = mainObject.getJSONArray("params"); //title of what you want
JSONObject paramsObject = params.getJSONObject(0);
JSONArray answerData = paramsObject.getJSONArray("answer_data_all");
JSONArray formData = paramsObject.getJSONArray("form_data_all");

String id = formData.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");
```

You should be able to extract all the values doing something like this. Although I will say I think the formatting is odd. You're using single member arrays that just contain other objects. It would make much more sense to either use one array to hold all the object or just separate JSONObject. It makes it much easier to read and easier to parse.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray feed = feedObject.getJSONArray("params");
    for(int i = 0; i<feed.length(); i++){
        JSONArray tf = feed.getJSONArray(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < tf.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject hy = tf.getJSONObject(j);
            String idt = hy.getString("id");
            String name = hy.getString("name");
        }
    }
```

**NOTE: the 'feedObject' variable is the JSONObject you are working with..Although this your type of JSON feed is kinda mixed in terms of string names and all but this should do for now..